# How do I use a variable in an argument line?

Tags: c++, qt4

I am using SOCI to make MYSQL connections from my QT4 C++ application.  I could hard code a mysql server IP, username, and password but I would rather pass this information in as a variable instead.

For example, I would like to do something like this, but there are no functions that accept these kinds of parameters:

```
char host [9];
sprintf(host, "192.x.x.x");
session sql(mysql, "host=%s db=dbname user=user password=password", host);
```

I also tried:

```
string host = "192.x.x.x";

session sql(mysql,
            boost::format("host=%1% db=dbname user=user password='pword'",
                          %host));
```

But this also fails.

UPDATE: I was able to solve the problem like so:

```
QString connection;
connection.append("host=" + host +
                  " db=dbname user=" + uname +
                  " password=" + pword);

session sql(mysql, connection.toLatin1().data());
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using QString's arg function.

```
session sql(mysql, QString("host=%1 db=%2 user=%3 password=%4").arg(sqlserver).arg(dbname).arg(user).arg(password));
```

I know it's ugly, and Qt should come up with a prettier solution, but it works.

Comment: error: no matching function for call to ‘soci::session::session(const soci::mysql_backend_factory&, QString)’ ??? think it needs a const char???

Comment: @user: after a brief glance over the documentation, I think you need to use .data()?

Answer (score 1):

Use [string streams](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iostream/stringstream/).

Then you can construct the string and concatenate variables as you go. Call `.str().c_str()` at the end.

Comment: You also need to use `.c_str()` at the end to get your `const char *`.

Comment: .str().c_str(), first to string and then to const char*

Answer (score 1):

You can't just arbitrarily pass any function that expects a string one that contains formatting and then a variable amount of whatever after it.  C++ simply doesn't work that way.  You need to build your string before passing it in.  How?  The other two answers provide ways even if they get the calling semantics of the `session` constructor wrong (that's your part to figure out).  You might also consider use of boost::format or, if you want to be evil, sprintf.

Comment: Ok, I think I did what you said, but I updated my original post with my problem...